# Null object reference on DB insert

Tags: android

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why I'm getting a null object reference when calling on the below method.  I'm showing my dbhelper class and my listview adapter class.  Essentially the portion of listview adapter which is handling my radiogroup onCheckedChanged and then sending data to sqlite database.

DBHelper class:

```
public void addListItem(String carmodel,String Condition, String x) {

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

 values.put(DBHelper.Model, carmodel);
 values.put(DBHelper.Condition, Condition);
 values.put(DBHelper.UPDATETIME, x);
 db.insert(TABLE_CARFACT, null, values);

 db.close(); 
}
```

And my listview adapter class is below.  Null object reference error is happening toward the bottom where I call db.addListItem(....).  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class ListCarsAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {


 private SQLiteDatabase uDatabase;
 private DBHelper uDbHelper;
public static final String TAG = "ListCarsAdapter";
private List<Car> mItems;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private DBHelper db;
public ListCarsAdapter(Context context, List<Car> listCars) {
  this.setItems(listCars);
  this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ? getItems().size() : 0 ;
}

@Override
public Car getItem(int position) {
  return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ?  getItems().get(position) : null ;
}

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ? getItems().get(position).getId() : position;
 }


 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View v = convertView;

  final ViewHolder holder;
  if(v == null) {
      v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_car, parent, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.txtCarName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_car_name);
      holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.scale);

      holder.radioGroup.setTag(position);
      v.setTag(holder);


    }
    else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
  }

  // fill row data
  final Car currentItem = getItem(position);
  if(currentItem != null) {
     holder.txtCarName.setText(currentItem.getCar());
     holder.radioGroup.setTag(currentItem.getAnswer());
  }


  holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
  holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();

  if(checked.indexOfKey(position)>-1){
     holder.radioGroup.check(checked.get(position));
  }else{
     holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
  }

  holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        String Answer = null;
        if(checkedId>-1){
           checked.put(position, checkedId);


           switch (checkedId) {
              case R.id.a1:
                 Answer = "r1";
                 break;
              case R.id.a2:
                 Answer = "r2";
                 break;
              case R.id.a3:
                 Answer = "r3";
                 break;
              case R.id.a4:
                 Answer = "r4";
                 break;
           }

           db.addListItem("testCar", Answer, getCurrentTimeStamp());  /*<--null object reference happening here*/


        }else{
           if(checked.indexOfKey(position)>-1)
              checked.removeAt(checked.indexOfKey(position));
        }

     }
   });



   return v;
 }


 public List<Car> getItems() {
   return mItems;
 }

 public void setItems(List<Car> mItems) {
  this.mItems = mItems;
 }

 class ViewHolder {
  TextView txtCarName;

  protected RadioGroup radioGroup;


 }


 public static String getCurrentTimeStamp(){
  try {

     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     String currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date()); // Find todays date

     return currentTimeStamp;
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

     return null;
  }
 }



}
```

Comment: Your all 3 references uDatabase, uDbHelper and db all point to null. You have not assigned an object to either of the three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `private DBHelper db;` is only defined but i dont see in your code that you are creating object of that class. Please instatiate that class somewhere in your `ListCarsAdapter` for example:

```
private DBHelper db;
public ListCarsAdapter(Context context, List<Car> listCars) {
  this.setItems(listCars);
  this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  db = new DBHelper();//<--your awesome object of DBHelper class
}
```